# In Brainfuck, how can I write a loop that prints a matrix whose elements are given by the user?

Tags: loops, matrix, printing, cell, brainfuck

I'm trying to make a Gaussian elimination in Brainfuck, but I can't figure out how to print a matrix of given numbers

`,>,` this receives the number of rows and columns;
`<[>>>+<<<-]>>>[<<[<+>>+<-]>[<+>-]>-]<<<` this determines how much elements the matrix will have (it basically does `rows*columns`)

Now I need to input the elements of the matrix itself. The simplest thing I thought about is to do a loop that receives from an input the number, saves it in a cell and decreases `rows*columns`, but how can I do a loop that every time moves to a new cell (and that obviously stops when I have a number of elements equal to `row*columns`) in order to not overwrite the already existing elements?

Answer (score 0):

Until now, your code just calculates rows*colums and preserves the number of columns. If you just want to read rows*columns inputs and all inputs are non-zero, then you can simply decrease your first cell for each input that was made

```
[ cells: rows*columns, columns, 0 (for finding first 0), value, value, value, ... ]

,>,<[>>>+<<<-]>>>[<<[<+>>+<-]>[<+>-]>-]<<< (your code)

[           while rows*columns is not 0
  >>>       leave an empty cell between column count and matrix (so bf can search for the first zero cell)
  [>]       go to the first empty cell
  ,         read input
  [<]<<     go back to rows*colums
  -         decrement rows*colums
]
```

if the input can also be 0, you should use an extra marker cell for each matrix cell. So you see if it is in use.

```
[ cells: rows*columns, columns, 0 (for finding first 0), value, marker(1), value, marker(1), value, marker(1) ... ]

,>,<[>>>+<<<-]>>>[<<[<+>>+<-]>[<+>-]>-]<<< (your code)

[           while rows*columns is not 0
  >>>       leave an empty cell between column count and matrix (so bf can search for the first zero cell)
  >         go to marker cell
  [>>]      go to the first empty marker cell
  +         set it to 1 so it marks that it is used
  <         go to its value cell
  ,         read input
  <[<<]<<   go back to rows*colums
  -         decrement rows*colums
]
```